# str_replace replace any character and space

Tags: character, str-replace

I have some strings like A Paper, B Wood, C Cotton and I need to delete the first letter and the space and have Paper, Wood, Cotton. I tried this.

```
<?php
    $str = 'A Paper';
    $new_str = str_replace('? ', '', $str);
    echo $new_str;
?>
```

How to write function str_replace like $new_str = str_replace('(any character) ', '', $str);

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the library function **substr_replace** as:

```
$str = substr_replace($str,$char,$pos,1);
```

**Edit**

For this case:

```
$new_str = substr_replace($str, '', 0, 2);
```

Comment: I used $new_str = substr_replace($str, '', 0, 2); and that is OK. I write this comment for others, because, I thing, that is better to understand the example above.

Comment: That's good that it resolved your query. I'm editing my answer with your example.